# OSB - JMS State String

Tags: jms, weblogic, osb

I have a proxy service calling a business service that put a message on a queue, my problem is that the State String on Weblogic Console remains "send transaction" instead of "visible", this cause my BAM consumer not be able to take this message from the queue. Is there any configuration that I need to do on proxy or business service to change this state? I also have the transactions required checked on proxy service to guarantee the message be removed only In case of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you on 11g as you refer to "proxy" (not pipeline) calling business service. 
Are you sure the proxy service is completing the action without errors?
If you are using an XA JMS connection factory to push to the JMS queue, are you sure the XA transaction is committing fully? Logs/weblogic JTA monitoring tab might have clues.

Alternately, first try using a non-XA connection factory and see if that works.

Comment: Are you sure the proxy service is completing the action without errors? Yes, because the message is removed from the source queue and on debbug I can see that the message don't pass on Error Handler. Are you sure the XA transaction is committing fully? Yes, I have a error destination queue configured for any error.

Comment: What happens when you manually insert a message using your business service? To answer your question, you dont need to do anything explicit to make the message visible apart from enduring successful txn completion. But if your JMS destination is in a different domain or maybe the way you invoke the JMS URL (eg improper hostname), the XA txn might not be committing properly

Comment: When I insert a message manually the State String shows "visible" and everything works. And yes, my destination queue is on different domain. I was using SAF but I have some problems with different versions of weblogic product in different domains, thats why I'm using OSB to send the message.

Comment: Ok. The manual insertion must specifically happen via "business service" test console, not through web logic console. If that fails, then you might need to ensure inter-domain trust is set up properly. You might see clues in server logs on both sides about why your txn might be failing to commit fully.

Comment: If you rule out other problems by trying out a non-XA connection factory first, then you might need to apply this to get XA to work: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLJTA/trxsecurity.htm#WLJTA394

Comment: I've tried by "business service" and it worked. I saw the log file and it gave me a clue: User [<anonymous>] is not authorized to invoke startCommit on a transaction branch. I also tried put a ServiceAccount on business service passing user and password but I had no success.

Comment: Yes.  You most likely need to set up inter domain trust as per the above link for global transactions to work across domains. Also check Oracle support etc.